# vim insert mode autocompletion by ctrl-p does not work after dot

Tags: vim

In vim insert mode, if there is a word `insert`, and if I typed `ins`, then type `ctrl-p`, vim will auto complete the word to `insert`.

I remember in my last PC if I type `data.ins` then type `ctrl-p`, vim will auto complete the word to `data.insert`, but since I bought a new PC, vim does not auto complete `data.ins`, how to fix this?

By the way if I type `b` on `t` of the word `data.insert`, vim will jump back to `d`, instead of `i`, I need to jump to `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the dot character somehow got to be a part of the `iskeyword` option. To verify this, you can look at the output of `:set iskeyword?` (note the final questionmark).

To fix this temporarily, you can do `:set iskeyword-=.`. To fix this permanently, find out where `iskeyword` is changed in your `.vimrc`.

The option `iskeyword` determines what characters Vim considers to be part of a "word". With a dot inside it, string like `data.insert` will be considered a single word, meaning you jump over them with a single `w`/`b`/`e`/... motion. Ctrl-p autocompletion looks whether the substring typed until now is part of a "word" in the rest of the document. Since you hadn't typed `data.insert` before, it doesn't find anything starting with `data.ins`. When you remove the dot from `iskeyword`, it will only look if something started with `ins` (like `insert`).

After you removed the dot, if you find yourself occasionally wanting to jump over the entire *dotted name*, you can use Vim's concept of WORDs (see `:h WORD`). You jump over WORDs using `W`/`B`/`E`/...

Comment: Hi, how to override the iskeyword setting in vimrc? it seems iskeyword is set by some 3rd party plugins, I have set iskeyword in the last line of .vimrc, but id does not affect, I have to do `:set iskeyword-=.` everytime in vim

Comment: In the `.vimrc`, you write it without a leading colon, but apart from that it should work. It could just be that a plugin is changing the setting later, on a certain event.Try disabling plugins one by one to find out which it is.

Comment: I need that plugin, how can I override the `iskeyword` setting only?

Comment: What plugin is it? Do you want to continue this discussion in chat?